# Eloquent relationships showing nothing or throwing SQL errors

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 models, User, Subject and Connection, which each has a table, users, subject and connection respectively.
The Connection table links together subject ids with user ids, so one user can have multiple different subjects, and vice versa.

From Connection i am finding all instances where subject_id == 1.

```
@foreach(... as $value) //Then is the two arrays the $value.
{"id":3,"user_id":"2","subject_id":"1","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}

{"id":2,"user_id":"1","subject_id":"1","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}
@endforeach
```

Through a foreach loop, i am trying to get the user from that.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function subject(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Subject');
}
```

$value->subject works fine, but $value->user just shows nothing.

I have no idea why it refuses to show users.
NB. I have multiple functions with the same name in different models, but that shouldn't matter, should it?

`$this->belongsToMany('User')` gives me the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dlh.connection_user' doesn't exist
(SQL:
select users.*,
  connection_user.connection_id as pivot_connection_id,
  connection_user.user_id as pivot_user_id from users
inner join connection_user on users.id = connection_user.user_id
where connection_user.connection_id = 3
)
```

I have tried this, but it just returns an empty array.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'connection', 'user_id');
```

Comment: Where are the (SQL) errors you're getting?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, that was because I was trying with $this->belongsToMany('User'). I realized it probably shouldn't be that, but the SQL it returned was this.


SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dlh.connection_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `users`.*, `connection_user`.`connection_id` as `pivot_connection_id`, `connection_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `connection_user` on `users`.`id` = `connection_user`.`user_id` where `connection_user`.`connection_id` = 3)

Comment: This error says `Table 'dlh.connection_user' doesn't exist` ... Does this table actually exist? Is this the table you're expecting to be used?

Comment: connection.user_id exists. but I can't change it to public function user_id(), because if I try $value->user_id it will just print the actual user_id. eg. 1, 2 etc.

Comment: The error doesn't mention `connection.user`, but `connection_user`. I see no reference to a `connection` table in this error. Your query selects data from the `users` table, but when starts doing stuff with `connection_user` ... I'm, not familiar with laravel, but my guess is you confused your table names somewhere...

Comment: Okay, I'll try to go through it all again, and return with my findings.

Comment: If you can't resolve it, you should post a more complete example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have many to many relation in your User Model you should have

```
class User extends Eloquent {

 public function subject()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject','connection_user','user_id', 'subject_id');
  }

}
```

and in your subject model

```
class Subject extends Eloquent {

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','connection_user','subject_id', 'user_id');
  }

 }
```

Then you can retrieve records

```
$subject= Subject::Find(1);
 @foreach ($subject->user as $user)
    do something
 @endforeach
```

check many to many relations in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)